# What is a EH-Number™?

Tags: pattern

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a number/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Number%22+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it an EH-number™.
If a number does not conform to the rule, I call it an OH-number™

Use the following examples below to find the rule:

| EH-numbers™ | OH-numbers™ |
| --- | --- |
| 8 | 4 |
| 588 | 234 |
| 4556 | 4557 |
| 1233 | 1234 |
| 7961 | 0998 |
| 45635 | 45636 |
| 34567 | 93456 |
| 8656783 | 8656784 |
| 2534534 | 2534535 |
| 8359081 | 8359089 |
| 8359082 | 8359080 |

CSV version:

```
EH-numbers™, OH-numbers™
8,         4
588,       234
4556,      4557
1233,      1234
7961,      0998
45635,     45636
34567,     93456
8656783,   8656784
2534534,   2534535
8359081,   8359089
8359082,   8359080
```

Comment: Does having a `0` at the front of `0998` change the eh-iness or the oh-iness of the number?

Comment: @boboquack : yes it change.

Comment: Then is it supposed to be there?

Comment: @boboquack : yes 998 is EH, 0998 is OH

Comment: Somebody tell me I'm not the only one to read the question and immediately think "Hip hop hurr-EH! OH!  EH!  OH!"

Answer (score 28, accepted):

My first guess:

> An EH-number has an even number of holes and an OH-number has an odd number of holes.

EH and OH stand for:

> Even-holed and Odd-holed

Tip for future (assuming the answer is correct):

> The font used in the CSV makes a 0 look like it has 2-holes, not the intended 1 (which by counting I think you wanted). Also, 9980 may have been better than 0998, it looks unsuspicious.

Comment: +1 Not sure if this is the expected answer, but it checks out. good job. Also, he probably made the numbers suspicious on purpose to give hints.

Comment: Good advice as well